# Change Form Size Depending on Screen Resolution

Tags: html, css, forms, resize

I've had a look online and via Stack but have only be able to find fixes for `C#` so far.

I've been working on a new Job Search Form - The actual form works great, however I'm having issues when I test it on different sized computer screens.

The form is supposed to look like this: A simple design.

[image: Form Example]
When I use the form to search our job boards, it works great. The problem that arises is when I use it on a different resolution screen, I will get an issue like this:

[image: Form Broken Example]
Now I believe this error has come from me actually coding in the size of the input bars:

```
<input name='Keywords' type='text' maxlength='64' size='50' id='Keywords' value='' placeholder="e.g freight forwarding" style="font-style:italic;"  x-webkit-speech />
```

Is there a way that I can code in the size so that it fits in depending on the size of the screen the user is viewing from?

Any help would be greatly appreciated it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D thank you for your comment. I've already included the section of code that I believe causes my Issue. I've not included all my code as I don't believe it to be relevant atm. I've simply set the size of my input boxes (shown in code above) so it does not resize when I use it on a different screen. I was after a method to resize these when the screen size changes.

Comment: One input tells us nothing. Where is the CSS...you are supposed to **demonstrate** the problem.